# Memcached doesnt allow to cache item larger that 1mb limit even if it was overrided

Tags: python, caching, memcached

Using `python-memcached==1.48`

Terminal:

```
memcached -I 10m
```

Python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import memcache
>>> mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
>>> print(mc.set('test', ''.join(['a' for x in xrange(1*1024*1024+1)])))
0
>>> print(mc.set('test', ''.join(['a' for x in xrange(1*1024*1024)])))
True
```

Can anybody reproduce this actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `python-memcache` what the maximum value size is before it will accept values larger than 1MB:

```
import memcache

mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'],
    debug = 0,
    server_max_value_length = 1024*1024*10
)
```